# Client Projects Google Sheet - How to update rows based on status?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet named Client Projects which lists all of the projects of all of the clients - which I can filter by the client's name. But what I would like to do is have a Status header with the options - Active and Inactive. and when I'll press inactive, it will automatically hide/delete the client's projects from the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
function UpdateInactiveRow(id){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urldb)
  var source =  ss.getSheetByName("Client Projects");

  var lookupRangeValues = source.getRange(1, 1, source.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();//get column id of lists all of the projects

  for(var i = 0; i < lookupRangeValues.length; i++){

    if(lookupRangeValues[i] == id){

       source.getRange(i+1, 2 ).setValue("inactive"); //this column 2 is status

    }
  }  

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate please? What exactly should I change here for this to work?

Comment: You need to have an id column for the name of your project list, when call the function and pass the id parameter it find id delete it ( I do not recommend deleting data like this but if you want you can use it, edit it a bit ) : 


  for(var i = 0; i < lookupRangeValues.length; i++){

    if(lookupRangeValues[i] == id){

    source.deleteRow(i+1);
   
    }
  }